# T-SQL Remove Duplicates from Groups BUT NOT GET TOP 1 FROM EACH GROUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

> I do **NOT** want to get top 1 from each group! Pay attention to the explanation which I have provided at the last portion of my question!

I have the following rows:

```
| Code | Type | SubType |    Date    |
|:----:|:----:|:-------:|:----------:|
|  100 |  10  |    1    | 17.12.2019 |
|  100 |  10  |    2    | 18.12.2019 |
|  100 |  10  |    2    | 19.12.2019 |
|  100 |  10  |    1    | 20.12.2019 |
```

What I need is to make groups of rows based on `Code`, `Type` and `SubType` columns. But not only should I keep the `Date` column, but I have to remove duplicate rows (based on `Code`, `Type` and `SubType` columns) from those groups which are in the middle as follows:

```
| Code | Type | SubType |    Date    |
|:----:|:----:|:-------:|:----------:|
|  100 |  10  |    1    | 17.12.2019 |
|  100 |  10  |    2    | 18.12.2019 |
|  100 |  10  |    1    | 20.12.2019 |
```

Let me to explain more about the scenario which leads to this situation, and thus I need to clean my data before displaying to the end user. I have a historical table which has 4 columns (`Code`, `Type`, `SubType` and `Date`). Each row of this table shows a change which have been occurred on the values of the fields of that row at a specific date. For instance, in the above example, there have been 4 changes on the row at 4 different dates. At first, the row has been generated with `Code = 100`, `Type = 10` and `SubType = 1` at `17.12.2019`. Then `SubType` has been changed to `2` at `18.12.2019`. Next day, at `19.12.2019`, `SubType` has been changed again to `2` (which is a duplicate in my case). Finally, `SubType` has been changed again to `1` at `20.12.2019`. In fact, I don't need to show the 3rd change as it is a duplicate in my case.

I tried using `Row_Number()Over(Partition by Code, Type and SubType Order By Date)`, but I was not successful.

Comment: Posting the exact same question does not make a new qusetion... If you feel that question I marked as a duplicate does not help then explain why.You do not do that. What you have in your expect result is most definitely the "first" row in the data. If that isn't the case then supply more sample data in your original question, explain why the linked duplicate is not a duplicate, and show your attempts.

Comment: @Larnu: you are sure right about repeativly posting the same question. However I am unsure how good the solution linked as duplicate applies to this question. This question seems like a gaps-and-island problem.

Comment: Hmm, youi might be right on that one, @GMB . The tiny sample data and expected results don't really help tell which. There are, however, still plenty of duplicates of that as well. I'll add one to the OP's original question. This, however, is stuill an **Exact** duplicate of their old one and should *really* be closed as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep the dates where something changes.  My recommendation is lag *on the date*:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by code, type, subtype order by date) as prev_cts_date,
             lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_cts_date is null or prev_cts_date <> prev_date;
```

One alternative is a `lag()` on each of the columns and then check each value for a change.  Not only is that cumbersome, but the logic gets much worse if `NULL` values are involved.

Here is logic is just asking:  "Is the previous date for the CTS combination the same as the previous date?"  If so, discard the record.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a gaps-and-island problem. Here is one approach using `row_number()`:

```
select code, type, SubType, Date
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by code, type, rn1 - rn2 order by date) rn
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            row_number() over(partition by code, type order by date) rn1,
            row_number() over(partition by code, type, SubType order by date) rn2
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where rn = 1
```

This defines group by taking the difference of row numbers over partitions of `code, type` against partitions of `code, type, subtype`. Then, we select the first record per group, using `row_number()` again.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bbe17c3f8dee8e0036cbcae5179ceb78)**:

```
code | type | SubType | Date      
---: | ---: | ------: | :---------
 100 |   10 |       1 | 17.12.2019
 100 |   10 |       2 | 18.12.2019
 100 |   10 |       1 | 20.12.2019
```